# need to parse a string with RegEx

Tags: regex, c#-3.0

I need to parse a string that looks like this:

*Some label was A B C, changed to ccc ddd.*

Here the words 'was' and ', changed to' and the dot at the end are parts of the syntax.

I need to parse it to extract following three strings:

"Some label"

"A B C"

"ccc ddd"

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
/([\w ]*) was ([\w. ]*), changed to ([\w. ]*)/
```

This is only a starting point that you will likely need to change depending on exactly what you want to be able to match in place of "A B C" on the like - right now we match word characters (letters, digits and underscore), spaces, and periods. The first character class doesn't match periods though, so if your labels contain periods you'll need to change that.

[Check it out in action here](https://regex101.com/r/fV3yZ6/1) - take a look at the matches on the right, and play around with it to see how it works.

Comment: By the way, to run this in C#, build your regex object using `Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);` and then match with `rgx.Matches(label_string)`

Comment: Thank you Devon, it work wonderfully! Now my question is: how do i change the regex expression to allow more special symbols in values: like slash, dash, dots, etc. My first label is usually contains only letters, but both values can include multiple special chars.

Comment: Example: End date was 2/11/2008 12:00:00 AM, changed to 1/1/2038 12:00:00 AM.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html , you will want to add things between the square brackets. For reference, the square brackets indicate Character Classes, and the circle brackets indicate Capture Groups